# Android animation between activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, android-transitions

I got a trouble when I do an animation between an activity and a fragment the animation for the activity is not working only the fragment move.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_from_left, R.animator.slide_in_from_right);
transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

The activity should go on the right, but the activity don't move.
I try this code for switching one fragment to another fragment and the previous fragment move on the right all works correctly.
Why when I use this on activity he doesn't move ?

Comment: You should know that Activity is contain Fragments, So that's mean only Fragments inside Activity can do the animation.

Comment: How can I avoid this

Comment: with Fragments you did right things. But with Activity you could use `finish()+overridePendingTransition()` to make the animation for Activity after finished